# Is $\{ a^i b^j c^k : i + 1000\ < j + 100 < k \}$ context-free?

Tags: formal-languages, context-free, pumping-lemma

I have this language:

$$ L = \{ a^i b^j c^k :  i + 1000\ < j + 100 < k  \}, $$

and what I believe is that we can't prove with the Pumping Lemma that it is not context-free, because we would always be able to choose $x$ as $b$, $v$ as $b$ and $y$ as $c$. For example, suppose we have the string $a^pb^{p+1000}c^{p+10000}$. We can choose $x$ as $b$, $v$ as $b$ and $y$ as $c$, and $uv^ixu^iz$ would always belong to $L$. But I can't find a grammar for $L$.

Comment: Have you considered the case $i = 0$?

Comment: Welcome to Computer Science! Your question is a rather basic one. Let me direct you towards our [reference questions](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/599) which cover some fundamentals you seem to be missing in detail. Please work through the related questions listed there, try to solve your problem again and edit to include your attempts along with the specific problems you encountered. Good luck!

Comment: @YuvalFilmus i > 0

Comment: I meant $i=0$ in the pumping lemma.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus ok I see i missed some corner case there. I'll fix that, but what if there weren't any tricky corner cases?